# Codeigniter upload library get thumb file name

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I can't find any documentation on this. I'm uploading images and using

```
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
```

to create a thumb and preserve the original image.

Is there a way to get the file name of the thumb image? `_thumb` is automatically added in the name for thumbnails but there's no function to extract the full name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There really is a much easier way of doing this:

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload())  // If file was uploaded
{           
    $data = $this->upload->data(); // Returns information about your uploaded file.
    $thumbnail = $data['raw_name'].'_thumb'.$data['file_ext']; // Here it is
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robert! I think your solution works best. It's simple and returns all the correct file data.

Answer (score 3):

CodeIgniter not providing any functions to extract the thumbnail name. It will add **_thumb** in your filename. If you want to write a custom function to get thumbnail name then use this.

```
function generate_thumb($filename, $path = '')
{
    // if path is not given use default path //
    if (!$path) {
        $path = FCPATH . 'somedir' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $path . $filename;
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 75;
    $config['height'] = 50;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        return FALSE;
    }
    // get file extension //
    preg_match('/(?<extension>\.\w+)$/im', $filename, $matches);
    $extension = $matches['extension'];
    // thumbnail //
    $thumbnail = preg_replace('/(\.\w+)$/im', '', $filename) . '_thumb' . $extension;
    return $thumbnail;
}
```

Input :

```
echo generate_thumb('someimage.jpg');
echo generate_thumb('other_image.png', FCPATH . 'dirname' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Output :

```
someimage_thumb.jpg
other_image_thumb.png
```

Hope this helps your. Thank you!!

Comment: @Robert code work only if you are generating the thumbnail at the same time of file upload. This code work with just a path or upload time both. It doesn't mean this code is good. :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
function general_thumbnail_image($source_image_path, $width, $height){

    $thumbnail_config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $thumbnail_config['source_image'] = $source_image_path;
    $thumbnail_config['thumb_marker'] = '_'.$width.'x'.$height;
    $thumbnail_config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $thumbnail_config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $thumbnail_config['width'] = $width;
    $thumbnail_config['height'] = $height;


    $this->load->library('image_lib', $thumbnail_config);

    if($this->image_lib->resize()){
        $result['status'] = True;

        //If you need complete base path of the thumbnail.
        $result['thumbnail_base_path'] = $this->image_lib->full_dst_path;

        //If you just need name of the thumbnail.
        $source_image_name = $this->image_lib->source_image;
        $extension = strrchr($source_image_name , '.');
        $name = substr($source_image_name , 0, -strlen($extension));
        $result['thumbnail_image_name'] = $name.$config['thumb_marker'].$extension;

        //If you need path similar to source image path.
        $source_image_path = $source_image_path;
        $extension = strrchr($source_image_path , '.');
        $name = substr($source_image_path , 0, -strlen($extension));
        $result['thumbnail_image_path'] = $name.$config['thumb_marker'].$extension;

    }
    else{
        $result['status'] = false;
        $result['error'] = $this->image_lib->display_errors('', '');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Calling function.

```
$thumbnail_result = $this->generate_thumbnail_image('./assests/images/apple.jpg', 180, 180);
print_r($thumbnail_result);
```

Output will look like:

```
    Array
   (
       [status] => 1
       [thumbnail_base_path] => D:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/assets/images/apple_180x180.jpg
       [thumbnail_image_name] => apple_180x180.jpg
       [thumbnail_image_path] => ./assets/images/apple_180x180.jpg 
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a function to generate the thumb image, like this :

```
    function generateThumb($fileName) {
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = './upload/images/clca/' . $fileName;
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 90;
    $config['height'] = 90;
    var file = "";
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    if(!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    } else {
        // Get File Name
        var file = $fileName."_thumb";
    }        
}
```

To call that function, firstly you have to upload your file, get the file name & call the function -> `$this->generateThumb($file_resp['file_name']);`

In your uploaded file folder, there will be 2 images (the original image & the generated thumb image with _thumb suffix)

To get the file name, I used "if" condition to ensure that there is no any errors in generating the thumb image, and then I join the $fileName+"_thumb". I used this way because I've checked the `$this->image_lib` object but there is no any references to the file name of generated thumb image.

EDITED :

- Sory, I'm a bit missed your question about getting file name of the thumb file, I've edited my post & the code :)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the code I tried something similar. You can generate a thumb without having to create a separate function and use `$this->upload->file_name . '_thumb'` but it does not get the file extension.